# Blazes still spawning in light!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am on a server (Timeless PVP Factions) with blaze spawners able to  be harvested, and I have made a blaze farm; however, my lighting isn't working to turn off the spawners. Usually light will work, but when the lights are on, blazes are still spawning. See this picture:

[image]

As you can see,  the blaze in the screenshot just spawned even though there are MANY lights on. What can I do to make sure that these spawners are deactivated when lights turn on?

Answer (score 4):

Although most hostile mobs require 7 light or less, blazes are special in that they only need 11 or less. This means that, from the light block, you need 2 or less spaces of air between any space where a blaze can spawn. It appears that your light spacing does not take that into account.

Comment: No, this server is completely 100% vanilla. The only mods I have are client side. However, incase something does, here is my [mod list](http://pastebin.com/rQi5n0Vn)

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice  
Is every space where a blaze's feet could be within 3 air blocks of a lamp?

Comment: Lava columns controlled by dispensers or pistons are a good way of lighting up blaze spawners on demand.